# What is this operator <<< in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I know that bash has the <, >, and 2> operators to redirect stdin, stdout, and stderr to a file, and that using >> for both out and err appends instead of flushing any available files first.
but I came across this line

```
IFS=',' read -a myarray <<< "$mystring"
```

which seems to read some data from a variable. What exactly is this operator? , and is there any << operator?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings

Comment: `<<` is the operator for `here-docs`. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<<< string` sends the contents of `string` to the command on standard input. (See [§3.6.7 "Here Strings" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings).)

`<<` is similar, but allows the string to be written across several lines; see [§3.6.6 "Here Documents" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) for details on how to use it.